# Поменять href ссылкам JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Пытаюсь поменять href всем ссылкам, все отрабатывает, однако в одном блоке ссылки не меняются.

Точно сказать не могу, возможно они добавляются после отработки скрипта, они в дополнительном поле WP. Пытался поменять им значение специально, через консоль браузера получилось, а через скрипт на сайте нет. Пытался менять их через время, но безуспешно.
Как можно решить вопрос?

```
                var links = document.querySelectorAll('.a_name');
                links.forEach(function(elem){
                  var href = elem.getAttribute('href');
                  elem.href = '#123';
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.a_name');
  [...links].forEach(function(elem){
  var href = elem.getAttribute('href');
  elem.href = '#123';
}
```

Comment: Должно помочь :( ?